# Pytest: Getting addresses of all tests

Tags: python, pytest

When I run `pytest --collect-only` to get the list of my tests, I get them in a format like `<Function: test_whatever>`. However, when I use `pytest -k ...` to run a specific test, I need to input the "address" of the test in the format `foo::test_whatever`. Is it possible to get a list of all the addresses of all the tests in the same format that `-k` takes?

Comment: Why do you possibly need that? To execute all the tests that `--collect-only` would get you, it's sufficient to run `pytest` without parameters. And if the set of tests has changed, your list is stale, whatever format it's in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In conftest.py, you can override the 'collection' hooks to print information about collected test 'items'.

You may introduce your own command line option (like --collect-only). If this option is specified, print the test items (in whichever way you like) and exit.

Sample conftest.py below (tested locally):

```
import pytest

def pytest_addoption(parser):
    parser.addoption("--my_test_dump", action="store", default=None,
        help="Print test items in my custom format")

def pytest_collection_finish(session):
    if session.config.option.my_test_dump is not None:
        for item in session.items:
            print('{}::{}'.format(item.fspath, item.name))
        pytest.exit('Done!')
```

For more information on pytest hooks, see:

http://doc.pytest.org/en/latest/_modules/_pytest/hookspec.html

Comment: How does `pytest_collection_finish` compare with `pytest_collectreport`? The latter is listed at [official plugin documentation](http://doc.pytest.org/en/latest/writing_plugins.html) while the former is not. Should we prefer one or the other, or do the functions have fundamentally different, uh, functions?

Answer (score 2):

The usage isn't as you specify it. From the documentation:
http://doc.pytest.org/en/latest/usage.html

```
pytest -k stringexpr  # only run tests with names that match the
                      # "string expression", e.g. "MyClass and not method"
                      # will select TestMyClass.test_something
                      # but not TestMyClass.test_method_simple
```

so what you need to pass to '-k' is a string contained in all the callable functions you want to check (you can use logical operator between these strings). For your example (assuming all defs are prefixed by a `foo::`:

```
pytest -k "foo::"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using -k switch, you don't need to specify the full path separated by colons. If the path is unique, you can use just part of the path. You need full path of tests only when you are not using -k switch.

e.g.

`pytest -k "unique_part_of_path_name"`

for `pytest tests/a/b/c.py::test_x`, you can use `pytest -k "a and b and c and x"`.

You can use boolean logic for -k switch.

BTW, `pytest --collect-only` does give the file name of the test in `<Module` line just above the test names of the file.